# Image preprocessing of finetune in ResNet

Tags: python, deep-learning

I want to finetune ResNet50 ImageNet pretrained model, and I have a few question about image preprocessing of finetune.

1. In ImageNet preprocessing, we need to subtract the mean of pixel ([103.939, 116.779, 123.68]). When I use my dataset to finetune, should I subtract mean of ImageNet or subtract the mean of my data.
2. I do see many people rescale the data to [0,1], but the pretrained model(ImageNet) use image scale in [0,255]. Why do people do that? Is it reasonable?

Comment: I would imagine that you'd get the best accuracy if you used the mean of imagenet. However, I don't think it would make a big difference. It would be really cool if you did an experiment and let us know!
Scaling between 0 and 1 is usually used when you have a number of different features of different scales. For image classification this isn't necessary, just make sure that all of your images have the same scaling and that the model was trained on images with the same scaling.

Answer (score 0):

In my honest opinion people overstate the impact of image preprocessing. The only truly important thing is that the test data is similar in value scale to the training data. There are some theoretical benefits of having a pre normalized dataset, with the usage of batch normalization, but in practice it never made much of a difference (2-4% Accuracy).

If you have a running model and you are trying to get those last few % better accuracy without having to increase the amount of parameter than I would suggest tweaking this to your use-case.

In my opinion there is no single method that works for every use-case, but a good starting point is to use the same preprocessing as ImageNet, because the features will be similar to the ones produced for the imagenet classification.

Comment: 2-4% is kind of a big deal

Answer (score 0):

1. I would try both. Subtracting your mean makes sense because generally one tries to get mean 0. Subtracting image net mean makes sense because you want the network as a feature extractor. If you change something that early in the feature extractor it could be that it doesn't work at all.
2. Just like the mean 0 thing, it is generally seen as a desirable property to have features within a fixed range or with a fixed standard deviation. Again, I can't really tell you what is better but you can easily try it. My guess is that there aren't too big differences.

Most important: Make sure you apply the same preprocessing steps to your training / testing / evaluation data.